# php multiple returns

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm new here and to php.
I've modified a custom script that was done for me a while ago to be able to output different font colors (css) depending on how old an article is ($rdate). The problem I have is that only 2 features are working so far, The "if" and "else" work, but the "elseif" statement keeps the same aspect as the "if" statement. Any idea what could cause that?

```
function pop_rdate($ps_id) {
    global $link, $today, $base_url, $config;
    $blog= f(q("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE ps_id='".$ps_id."'", $link));
            $rdate = date('F d, Y', $blog->review_date);
            if (strtotime("now") > strtotime("+6 month", strtotime($rdate))) {
   return "<span class='med'>".$rdate."</span>";
}               elseif (strtotime("now") > strtotime("+12 month", strtotime($rdate))) {
   return "<span class='warning'>".$rdate."</span>";
}               else {
   return "<span class='good'>".$rdate."</span>";
}
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime("now") > strtotime("+12 month", strtotime($rdate)`

will also be `strtotime("now") > strtotime("+6 month", strtotime($rdate))`

So your condition is wrong.   a > 12 is also > 6

You should use

```
if (strtotime("now") > strtotime("+12 month", strtotime($rdate))) {
   return "<span class='warning'>".$rdate."</span>";
}              
elseif (strtotime("now") > strtotime("+6 month", strtotime($rdate))) {
   return "<span class='med'>".$rdate."</span>";
}               else {
   return "<span class='good'>".$rdate."</span>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the first `if-statement` will be true for the same values as the second (elseif) statement. So it will never go into the `elseif` body.

```
if (strtotime("now") > strtotime("+12 month", strtotime($rdate))) {

    return "<span class='warning'>".$rdate."</span>";

} elseif (strtotime("now") > strtotime("+6 month", strtotime($rdate))) {

    return "<span class='med'>".$rdate."</span>";

} else {

    return "<span class='good'>".$rdate."</span>";

}
```